# divide each line in equal part

Tags: sed, awk

I would be happy if anyone can suggest me command (sed or AWK one line command) to divide each line of file in equal number of part. For example divide each line in 4 part.

Input:

```
ATGCATHLMNPHLNTPLML
```

Output:

```
ATGCA THLMN PHLNT PLML
```

Comment: You could use the `FIELDWIDTHS` feature of `awk`, e.g.: `awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="5 5 5 5" } { for(i=1; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); print $NF }'`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1):

This should work using GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/(.{4})/\1 /g'
```

- `-r` is needed to use extended regular expressions
- `.{4}` captures every four characters
- `\1` refers to the captured group which is surrounded by the parenthesis `(` `)` and adds a space behind this group
- `g` makes sure that the replacement is done as many times as possible on each line

A test; this is the input and output in my terminal:

```
$ echo "ATGCATHLMNPHLNTPLML" | sed -r 's/(.{4})/\1 /g'
ATGC ATHL MNPH LNTP LML
```

Comment: \1 works in plain sed, too, it's `()` and `{}` that needs the `-r` (without it, you have to use `\(\)` and `\{\}`).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect awk is not the best tool for this, but:

```
gawk --posix '{ l = sprintf( "%d", 1 + (length()-1)/4);
    gsub( ".{"l"}", "& " ) } 1' input-file
```

If you have a posix compliant awk you can omit the --posix, but --posix is necessary for gnu awk and since that seems to be the most commonly used implementation I've given the solution in terms of gawk.

Answer (score 0):

#### perl

`perl` might be a better choice here:

```
export cols=4
perl -ne 'chomp; $fw = 1 + int length()/$ENV{cols}; while(/(.{1,$fw})/gm) { print $1 . " " } print "\n"'
```

This re-calculates field-width for every line.

#### coreutils

A GNU coreutils alternative, field-width is chosen based on the first line of `infile`:

```
cols=4
len=$(( $(head -n1 infile | wc -c) - 1 ))
fw=$(echo "scale=0; 1 + $len / 4" | bc)

cut_arg=$(paste -d- <(seq 1 $fw 19) <(seq $fw $fw $len) | head -c-1 | tr '\n' ',')
```

Value of `cut_arg` is in the above case:

```
1-5,6-10,11-15,16-
```

Now cut the line into appropriate chunks:

```
cut --output-delimiter=' ' -c $cut_arg infile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;s/./X/g;s/^\(.*\)\1\1\1/\1 \1 \1 \1/;G;s/\n/&&/;:a;/^\n/bb;/^ /s/ \(.*\n.*\)\n\(.\)/\1 \n\2/;ta;s/^.\(.*\n.*\)\n\(.\)/\1\2\n/;ta;:b;s/\n//g' file
```

Explanation:

- `h` copy the pattern space (PS) to the hold space (HS)
- `s/./X/g` replace every character in the HS with the same non-space character (in this case `X`)
- `s/^\(.*\)\1\1\1/\1 \1 \1 \1/` split the line into 4 parts (space separated)
- `G` append a newline followed by the contents of the HS to the PS
- `s/\n/&&/` double the newline (to be later used as markers)
- `:a` introduce a loop namespace
- `/^\n/bb` if we reach a newline we are done and branch to the `b` namespace
- `/^ /s/ \(.*\n.*\)\n\(.\)/\1 \n\2/;ta;` if the first character is a space add a space to the real line at this point and repeat
- `s/^.\(.*\n.*\)\n\(.\)/\1\2\n/;ta` any other character just bump along and repeat
- `:b;s/\n//g` all done just remove the markers and print out the result

This work for any length of line, however is the line is not exactly divisible by 4 the last portion will contain the remainder as well.